# How to avoid fuzzy printing after a screen capture?

Tags: vb.net, printing, gdi+

I'm using the code below to capture and print a windows form.  The problem is that it prints out very fuzzy.  Is there any way to have it print more clearly?

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Public bmp1 As Bitmap
Private WithEvents printDocument1 As New PrintDocument

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim L, T, W, H As Integer
    L = form1.Left : T = form1.Top : W = form1.Width : H = form1.Height

    Dim Bmp0 As New Bitmap(W, H)
    Dim g0 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp0)

    g0.CopyFromScreen(L, T, 0, 0, New Size(W, H))
    g0.Dispose()
    bmp1 = New Bitmap(Bmp0, 750, 562)

    printDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: How does the bitmap look before the `.Print()`? Perhaps the printer is fuzzying it up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Bitmap.Height and VerticalResolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221359/difference-between-bitmap-height-and-verticalresolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, your printing settings (or limited capabilities) might be the culprit.

You can try changing your bitmap resolution to see if it improves the output.

```
bmp1.SetResolution(dpX, dpY)
```

Printing my own form using your code, I get acceptable output.

Or maybe our definitions of "very fuzzy" are very different. :-)

Comment: Changing (750,562) to (938,703) then using bmp1.SetResolution(120,120) is a huge improvement.  Thanks.