# C# Whats the difference between Image.VerticalResolution and Image.Width

Tags: c#, image, width, resolution

As the subject says: Whats the difference between Image.VerticalResolution and Image.Width.  Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221359/difference-between-bitmap-height-and-verticalresolution

Comment: I think you might see here! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221359/difference-between-bitmap-height-and-verticalresolution

Answer (score 0):

No, the vertical resolution is the number of pixels per inch, vertically (height-wise).
The horizontal resolution would be the number of pixels per inch horizontally (width-wise)

`Image.Width` and `Image.Height` would be the exact width and height in pixels.

An image width a resolution of 100DPI, and a `width` and `height` of 200 (pixels) would display as a 2 by 2 inch image.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

`Image.VerticalResolution` gets the vertical resolution of the image in pixels per inch. Similarly, `Image.HorizontalResolution` does this across the screen

`Image.Width` gives the exact width of the image in pixels. `Image.Height` would give the exact width in pixels

Answer (score 0):

The Image.VerticalResolution = Gets the vertical resolution, in **pixels per inch**, of this Image.

Image.Width = The **width, in pixels**, of this Image.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.drawing.image.verticalresolution%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.drawing.image.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for more details.